# How to double the number of elements of the row in Excel?

Tags: excel-formula

In 1st row I generated random numbers, I want to keep the range of the element while doubling the number of elements in the next row. Ex)If the 1st row has 5 elements, 2nd row 5x2=10, 3rd= 10x2=20 and so on.

Comment: can you show us what you have done/tried to this point.  Mock up a table that shows what you want and expect.  A one sentence description is not usually enough to go off.

Comment: What is an "element"? Do these correspond to columns? I have no idea what you are trying to do or what the problem is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

if you have your value in `A1` then write in `A2 = 2*A1`.

Therefore you will have that `Ai = 2 * A(i-1)`  where `i` is any number in
the naturals (up to 2^20 rows which is the limit in an excel sheet).

[image]

If this works remember to mark this answer as a solution.

Have a good day.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. What I want is not doubling the values of each row. doubling the number of elements in row.

Comment: What do you mean by elements? Do you mean columns?

Answer (score 0):

This is a confusing question. I think what you want is to take a formula that happens X number of times in the first row, and cause that formula to occur in twice as many cells in the second row, twice that again in the third, and so on.

If that is the case you can wrap your formula in these functions:

`=IF(COUNT(1:1)*2>=COLUMN(),Put your formula here,"")`

Put that in the second row and drag across and down as far as you need it to.

Let me know if that doesn't do what you wanted.